# Update With SELECT FROM Table GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table material :

```
- id: int,
 - name : varchar(100),
 - content: varchar(255),
 - quantity : double,
```

the query without using group by

```
1, product1, content1, 25
2, product2, content2, 4 
3, product1, content3, 35
4, product3, content4, 15
```

the query with group by and SUM quantity

```
 product1, content1, 25
 product2, content2, 4 
 product3, content4, 15
```

when I want to update a quantity = 0 of the first id: 1, product1, content1, 25, I would make an update of the quantity = 0 for all materials that have the same name of the material
For example:

```
1, product1, content1, 0
2, product2, content2, 4 
3, product1, content3, 0
4, product3, content4, 15
```

I tried with :

```
Update 'material' as m  
INNER JOIN  (SELECT i1.produit FROM 'material' m1   GROUP BY m1.name) m1   
ON(m1.name = m.name) SET quantity = 0
```

but I have not the result :

Comment: And what is the exact error message or unexpected behaviour you experience when you execute the above sql statement? I have a guess, but I do not like to guess.

Comment: No you have added the sql server tag as well. Mysql and sql server are 2 different products, which one do you truly use?

Comment: @Shadow, yes i know, just an error ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following;)

```
UPDATE `material` AS m  
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT m1.name
    FROM `material` m1
    GROUP BY m1.name
    HAVING COUNT(m1.name) > 1) m2   
ON m2.name = m.name
SET m.quantity = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

@Reno, This query for the first id
but when I would choose whatever id
for example, I would choose the second id or whatever id
not necessarily the prermier id.
for example when i choose the second id : 
i would dipaly

```
1, product1, content1, 10
2, product2, content2, 0
3, product1, content3, 20
4, product3, content4, 15 
5, product2, content5, 0
```

and for example when i choose the fourth id : 
i would dipaly

```
1, product1, content1, 10
2, product2, content2, 30
3, product1, content3, 20
4, product3, content4, 0
5, product2, content5, 35
6, product3, content6, 0
```